# Dynamic Stack Memory Reallocation

Tags: c++, memory, realloc, stack

I'm fairly new to C++ and new to pointers as well. I'm currently working on a stack and was trying to reallocate the memory for the stack as the size of the stack reaches the top however, I'm running into issues. I've already done a lot of research both on Google and stack overflow and have found some information helpful but since I'm so new to stacks and C++ I'm still having issues. I was hoping some bright and intelligent people could at least point me in the right direction.

now... Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#define STACKMAX 20
using namespace std;

template <class T> class StackTemplated {
private:
    int top;
    T   values[STACKMAX];
public:
    StackTemplated();
    void    push(T i);
    T       pop(void);
    bool    empty(void);
 }; 


template <class T> StackTemplated<T>::StackTemplated() {
    top = -1;
}

template <class T>void StackTemplated<T>::push(T i) {
if (top == STACKMAX - 1) {

    // reallocate top of stack. (this is the area I'm having issues)
    char * string1;
    string1 = (char *)calloc(STACKMAX, sizeof(char));

        if (top == STACKMAX - 1) {
            cout << "The stack didn't re-allocate.";
            exit(1);
        }

} else {
    top++;
    values[top] = i;
}
}   

 template <class T> T StackTemplated<T>::pop(void) {
if (top < 0) {
    printf("%", "Stack underflow!");
    exit(1);
} else {
    return values[top--];
}
}   

template <class T> bool StackTemplated<T>::empty() {
return (top == -1);
}
```

Comment: Note that "C/C++" is not a language. C and C++ are separate languages; in this case, you are using C++.

Comment: I've removed the references to C in the question and tags.

Comment: Having `pop()` return an object as well as pop an object is a fairly bad design. It makes it very difficult to to use the stack in an exception safe manner (it makes the strong exception safety guarantee particularly difficult to achieve), because the operation of popping the value off the stack (which modifies the stack) is followed by the operation of copying the return value into the caller's code (which might throw). (See [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm) for more discussion on the matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't want to reallocate the top of the stack. Rather, you want to allocate a new array of values which is large enough to hold the new values. Also, since you need to reallocate the array, `values` should be a pointer.

But how about we forget all this. If we're working in c++, let's use what c++ offers us to make our lives easier. After that's done, then try open things up, if you really feel the need.

One of the things I'm referring to is your use of `calloc`. Using `calloc` is a *bad* idea, particularly when using templates. The problem is that since `calloc` has no type information, it won't do something as basic as calling a constructor. Constructors are *very* important in OOP, since they guarantee that an object's invariance when it is created. Instead, use the `new[]` keyword, like

```
values = new T[STACKMAX];
```

This allocates an array of `T` of `STACKMAX` length. Of course, as Greg points out, you should reconsider the use of `STACKMAX`, and use a variable instead. Also, `values` shouldn't be a static array, but should instead have type `T*`.

Another thing I was referring to is the fact that you are really trying to implement an array which grows dynamically as needed. In c++, we call such a structure a `vector`. If you use a vector, your entire code reduces to

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class StackTemplated {
private:
    std::vector<T> vec;

public:
    StackTemplated() { } // the constructor is trivial; in fact, you can leave it out if you want
    void    push(T i);
    T       pop(void);
    bool    empty(void);
};

template<class T>
void StackTemplated<T>::push(T i) {
    vec.push_back(i);
}

template<class T>
T StackTemplate<T>::pop(void) {
    T top = vec.back();
    vec.pop_back();
    return top;
}

template<class T>
bool StackTemplate<T>::isEmpty(void) {
    return vec.size() == 0;
}
```

That's all. It's a lot less hairy if you can use an existing data structure to implement the new data structure.

Once you get really comfortable with how a `vector` works (and there's plenty of explanations / documentation on the web), *then* try implementing the functionality yourself. Bottom line is, implementing a data structure is a lot easier if you know exactly how it's supposed to behave.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list of a few things I noticed:

- `STACKMAX` is a constant. If you're expanding the stack, how will you keep track of how big it currently is?
- The `values` member is a fixed-size array. You won't be able to change the size of it dynamically without changing how this is declared and allocated.
- `calloc()` allocates a new chunk of memory with the number of bytes you specify. You'll need to somehow copy the existing stack into the new memory block, and free the previous one.
- You're allocating only `STACKMAX` bytes in the call to `calloc()`. You'll probably want to scale this by `sizeof T`, in case `T` is not a `char`.

There will be a lot of details for you to fix up once you address these major points. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare your values like

```
T* vaules;
```

Then use new to create it not calloc. You will need to keep track of the top of the stack and size of it. As Greg says when you grow the stack make sure and copy data over and clean up the old one.